# How I change the color of table fonts/ contents with inline CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is my table format please tell me how i change the alphabets color in table

```
<table border="1" background="images/haya1.jpg" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10" width="30%" align="center" bordercolor="brown" bgcolor="red">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Class</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Abdullah</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td><b>Five</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Urdu</td>
        <td><b>Five</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Abdullah Decleared as Fail</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The best way is to start by reading a little bit about css. Follow a beginner tutorial for example. It is much faster then asking a question here and getting an answer.

Comment: Yeah Thanks.. I think so i'ld go there and read about CSS.. Sorry For Taking Your Precious Time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think So this is the best way..

```
 <tr style="color: yellow">
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Subject</th>
     <th>Class</th>
  </tr>
```